# How Do i get the heights ranked Decade of a movie?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by, mysql-workbench

I'm new to my SQL I came across a question which I couldn't solve i will list down the tables and what I attempt to do so please help!

**The question is: Which decade has the highest average ranked movies?**

Comment: It's good programming practice to qualify all columns when several tables are involved. E.g. `m.movieid` instead of just `movieid`.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should also specify the expected result!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

```
SELECT floor(m.year / 10) * 10 decade
FROM  movies m
INNER JOIN rate r on m.movieid = r.movieid
GROUP BY m.movieid, decade
ORDER BY avg(r.rank) desc
LIMIT 1
```

This gives you the decade that has the highest averaged ranked movie.

Side note: your original queries had issues - namely, column `movieid` is ambiguous since it exists in both tables and is not prefixed with a table name.

Comment: what does floor mean?

Comment: @KaithXXX: the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor) is your friend. `floor(1997 / 10)` gives you `199`.

Comment: hey, can limit be replaced?